# Getting Windows Visual Studio 2017 for Mac

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, sfml

I just came back from a summer camp that utilized Visual Studio Code 2017 (on a windows machine) and I brought back the project to further work on at home. The problem is that I have a Mac and the project is not compatible. I have been trying to download the 2017 version for mac but it just redirects to downloading the 2019 version. Is there any way to work around this? If not, please tell me what is the difference between that version and my mac version and if there is a way to convert it. (Note: I am using C++ and SFML.)

Comment: The differences between VS on Windows and on MacOS will likely be, in themselves, greater than the differences between VS2017and VS2019. So why not just go with VS2019?

Answer (score 0):

Visual studios community for mac does not support c++, if you want to stick with a true IDE I recommend [Clion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) otherwise vscode the text editor is what I use and the majority of developers.